# Multistep form and progress bar logic react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a logic problem in the construction of my form that I cannot solve.
My form consists of two components, one parent which controls the steps and the other, the child which allows you to view a progress bar. Progress bar and form steps are dynamic. I would like the step of the form and the progress bar to be synchronized in order to color the progress bar in green at each step.

The parent component :

```
export default function MultiStepsForm() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);

  //functions to control steps 
  const prevStep = ()=> {
    setStep(step - 1)
  }
  const nextStep = ()=> {
   setStep(step + 1);
  }

  
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <ProgressBar
      step={step}/>
      <div className={styles.main_container}>
        <div className={styles.forms_container}>
          {step === 0 && (<Step1
          nextStep={nextStep}/>)}
          {step === 1 && (<Step2
          nextStep={nextStep}
          prevStep={prevStep}/>)}
          {step === 2 && (<Step3
          prevStep={prevStep}/>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and the child component :

```
function ProgressBar({step}) {
    const progressSteps = [
      {id:1, name: "step1"},
      {id:2, name: "step2"},
      {id:3, name: "step3"}
    ]

  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <ul className={styles.progress_wrapper}>
            {progressSteps.map((step, i) =>(
            <li className={styles.progress_step} key={i} data-before={step.id}>
                <div className={styles.progress_marker}></div>
                <div className={styles.progress_text}>
                    <h4 className={styles.progress_title}>{step.name}</h4>
                </div>
            </li>))}
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

I tried this method inside the child component to have a state allowing me to change the class name depending on whether the state is true or false. But my logic is not good and causes an Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(false);
progressSteps.forEach((_,index)=>{
        if(step===index){
            setActiveStep(!activeStep);
        } activeStep;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

When your component loads, `setActiveStep()` is called, which then re-renders your component, so `setActiveStep()` is called again...

To only trigger your `forEach()` function when the component mounts and when the step changes, you would use a `useEffect()`

```js
const progressSteps = [
  {id:1, name: "step1"},
  {id:2, name: "step2"},
  {id:3, name: "step3"}
]

function ProgressBar({ step }) {
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        progressSteps.forEach((_, index) => {
            step === index && setActiveStep(prevState => (!prevState));
        })
    }, [step])
    
    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

However this still won't work for what you're trying to achieve, `activeStep` will just change between `true` and `false` everytime you change the `step`.

What you can do instead is conditionally render based on whether the `step` is equal to the index:

```js
{progressSteps.map((_, index) => (
  <React.Fragment key={index}>
    {index <= step ? (
      index === step ? (        
        <p style={{ color: "#db7777" }}>I am active</p>
      ) : (
        <p style={{ color: "green" }}>I am completed</p>
      )
    ) : (
      <p style={{ color: "grey" }}>I am not active</p>
    )}
  </React.Fragment>
))}
```

[image: Edit bold-moon-ob34j4]